# Detecting UI "glitches" in QT

Tags: qt, user-interface, glib

How can I detect when something is doing too much work on the main thread, causing the UI to "glitch" (i.e. not feel "smooth")?

I'm looking to be able to generate a warning like Android does:

```
 I/Choreographer(1378): Skipped 55 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

I'm using QT 5.4 with glib.

Comment: Could you clarify what sort of answer you're looking for here? For example, are you looking for hang detection in general, or an exact frame count like Android provides, etc?

Comment: I'd like to be able to track down exactly which event caused the UI to "hiccup" and by how much time or frames.

Comment: Teams that possess the codebase have usually have the code with extensive logging that can enabled for certain modules etc. That would help to analyze.